# how can i test FB.login in android device

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to figure out this Facebook unity plugin. I can login and get the info i want ( profile pic, user name ...etc ) by entering access token in editor. But when build my app and try to login nothing happens. So i got 2 questions.

-Is it possible to log in with an app that is in development mode but not in editor in android device?
-If so, is it possible to see a Login Page while logging in instead of Editor login page ( the one that asks accsess token)

```
fb. Init( fb.OnInitComplete, fb.OnHideUnity, fb.authResponse);


fb.Login("email,publish_actions", AuthCallBack);
```

i just use these two codes just so you know

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your key hash from the editor into facebook settings for android. Just take a look at the keyhas exporting part of the [documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)(5. section). Beaware if you are signing with your relese key and not debug keystore. Also don't forget to add the hash id to your developer account under Android tab.